# Forms Services does not accept the certificate of an WebService

Tags: web-services, forms-services, certificate

I've got a InfoPath form with a reading data connection to a SOAP WebService that is secured by https and basic http authentication. The form is hosted in Forms Services an the data connection is configured in a udcx file in the site collection.

When I open the form in SharePoint and it tries to query the data connection, it fails and I get the following error in the SharePoint ULS log:

> The root of the certificate chain is not a trusted root authority

I checked the certificates of the SharePoint machine account: The root certificate is in the trusted root authorities and the intermediate is also set right.

When I open the WebServices WSDL in an IE browser on the server, the certificate is accepted without problems.

Am I missing something? Do I have to trust this change at another place too? Maybe for the App Pool user or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I didn't know this, but SharePoint does not use the root authorities from the Windows certificates store, it has its own managment of certificates.

So we had to use the Central Administration to add the root certificate:

- Security
- Manage trust
- New
- Give it a name and browse the root certificate
- OK

Then it worked ...